# how to retrieve a column's values in order to update a column total

Tags: ag-grid

I have a pinned row that acts as a column's total, which works fine using gridOptions.pinnedBottomRowData. I need to update this value when the columns' cells' values change but I cannot find a means of accessing the column values to do so. What's the best means of updating a column total when it's columns' cells' values change?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the total on cell value changed or value setter function.

```
this.gridOptions.onCellValueChanged = function (event) {
    if (event.colDef.colId == "ColumnName") {
       //Logic to update the total row value
       total = total + event.data[event.colDef.field]
    }
}
```